# How can I get Add products link on Backend Products Information Page

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, custom-options, selection

I need to add products from Backend  Products Information Page, how can i get add products link on products information page.

Comment: add product means you want to create new product from front end?

Comment: @GopalPatel : add products link ::  https://snag.gy/LRaVmf.jpg     to product information ::  https://snag.gy/qtZSON.jpg

Comment: @GopalPatel : check my question again and i attached screen shots.

Comment: follow  this url http://www.herveguetin.com/add-a-button-to-admin-product-edit-page/